# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop even tho it has unique key React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so i wanted to render array but it keeps on saying , Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop even tho it has unique key, my array contains three elements and it does not even render the third array properly, the button doesnt even work of third li for some reason.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import fire from "./firebase";
import firebase from "firebase"
import { useState } from "react"
import Header from "./header"
import Nav from "./nav"
import { NavLink, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import AudioPlayer from "./audioplayer"   

const Music = ({ match }) => {
    const audioRef = useRef();
    const audioPlayer = audioRef.current
    const [audioSrc, setAudioSrc] = useState()
    const [musics, setMusics] = useState([])
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
    const [pfp, setPfp] = useState(null)
    const [audioTitle, setAudioTitle] = useState(null)
    const { params: { uID } } = match;
    var userName;
    var tracksTitle = [];
    useEffect(()=>{
        firebase.database().ref("users/"+uID+"/praivate/login credentials").on("value", (snapshot)=>{
            setUser(snapshot.val().userName)
            setUser(snapshot.val().userName)
        })
        firebase.database().ref("users/"+uID+"/public/profile/pic").on("value", (snapshot)=>{
            console.log(snapshot.val().pfpUrl)
            setPfp(snapshot.val().pfpUrl)
        })
    }, [])
    var music;

    //maybe the problem is over here somewhere
    useEffect(()=>{
        firebase.database().ref("users/"+uID+"/public/songs/").on("value", (snapshot)=>{
            //stores data in music.
            music = snapshot.val()
            //gets all title of the data
            Object.values(music).forEach((value)=>{  
                tracksTitle.push(value.title)//pushes titles to tracksTitle
            })
            setMusics(tracksTitle) //stores all track title in musics
        })
       
    }, [uID])

    const [progVal, setProgVal] = useState("0%")
    function update(event){
        let duration = (event.target.currentTime/event.target.duration)*100
        setProgVal(duration)
    }
    
    function play(event){
        const value = event.target.getAttribute("value")
        console.log(value)
        if(value){
            firebase.database().ref("public/songs/"+value).on("value", (snapshot)=>{
                setAudioSrc(snapshot.val().aduioURL)
            })
        }
        setAudioTitle(value)
        audioPlayer.play()
        
    }

    function playAudio(){
        audioPlayer.play()
    }

    

    function stop(event){
        audioPlayer.pause()
    }

   
    
    return(
        <>
            <Nav />
            <div id = "profile" className = "main">
                <audio id = "player" ref = {audioRef} src = {audioSrc} name = "audioplayer" onTimeUpdate = {update}>
                </audio>
                <div class = "profile-container">
                    <div className = "cover-pic">
                        <img src = "" />
                        <div className = "pfp">
                            <img src = {pfp} height = "100" width = "100"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className = "User-Name">
                            <h1>{user}</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "tabsContainer">
                    <div class = "tabs-holder">
                    <NavLink to = {"/u/"+uID+"/music"}><button><span>Music</span></button></NavLink>
                        <button><span>Playlist</span></button>
                        <button><span>About</span></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
               
                <div class = "music-content-container">
                    <div class = "music-box">
                        <div class = "user-musics">
                            <ul>
                                {musics && musics.map((name, i)=>{
                                    console.log()
                                    return(
                                        <>
                                            //it does not render the third array properly
                                            <li key = {i}><button onClick = {play} value = {name}>Play</button>{name}</li>
                                        </>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <AudioPlayer progVal = {progVal} stop = {stop} playAudio = {playAudio}/>
            <Header />
        </>
    )
    }  
export default Music
//
```

Can you guys please help me to figure out the problem, thank you in  advance.

update: my data from firebase looks like this:

[image]

and this code will select title of each data

```js
useEffect(()=>{
        firebase.database().ref("users/"+uID+"/public/songs/").on("value", (snapshot)=>{
            //stores data in music.
            music = snapshot.val()
            console.log(music)
            //gets all title of the data
            Object.values(music).forEach((value)=>{ 
                 
                tracksTitle.push(value.title)//pushes titles to tracksTitle
            })
            setMusics(tracksTitle) //stores all track in musics
        })
```

[image]

the button of "fikka fikka" doesnt even work when i hover over the "fikka fikka" it doesnt even change the cursor to text curosr while in ed sheeran and one direction it doesnt have that problem

Comment: For one you're using the index of the array as the key. This will cause problems. If the songs have unique names you could use the name itself as the key. Your use of fragments is also problematic. In this case using fragments makes close to no sense.

Comment: @Laras thank you, i tried that, but i dont know why, the third rendered  item is not being rendered properly, i cannot select the text and i cannot click on button too.

Comment: So, if I'm reading this correctly, `musics` is simply an array of the titles? Is the react key error resolved with one of the solutions provided here? Can you describe a bit more what you mean the 3rd list item isn't working? Is it *just* the 3rd? (The 1st, 2nd, 4th, 5th, etc.. all work?) If the react key issue is resolved and you've now some new error then might I suggest asking a new question for the new issue?

Comment: In that last screencap it appears the mapping of `li` elements worked exactly as expected. Seems like *something* (an invisible element) is overlaying your UI and not allowing clicks to go through. Have you inspected the DOM as well to see what all is being rendered to the screen?

Comment: @DrewReese yes i went to inspect element, and it shows everything is rendered properly it has its value and calss name

Comment: Well, the list elements themselves have no classnames assigned to them, but I was referring more anything *else* in the UI that may be covering  them from the mouse, i.e. some non-visible, absolutely positioned elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

React keys need to be on the outer-most returned element from the mapping.

```
{musics && musics.map((name, i)=>{
  return(
  <Fragment key={i}>
    //it does not render the third array properly
    <li>
      <button onClick={play} value={name}>Play</button>
      {name}
    </li>
  </Fragment>)
})}
```

Notice here that in order to do this the react fragment shorthand is incompatible, you ***must*** use the `Fragment` component. Or since there is only a single element the `Fragment` is mostly useless, remove it and place the key on the `li` where it was.

```
{musics && musics.map((name, i)=>{
  return(
  <li key={i}>
    <button onClick={play} value={name}>Play</button>
    {name}
  </li>)
})}
```

Comment: This solution also uses the index in the array as the key, which is strongly discouraged in React.

Comment: @LarsHoldaas Discouraged, yes, prohibited, not at all. It meets the criteria of acceptability for usage, i.e. it doesn't appear the array is being reordered or elements added/removed. From what I can tell, the array elements simply toggle a play state. OP's question isn't about this though.

Comment: hmm, thanks for the answer, but third list is still not being rendered properly, when i click the button it does not work, even the text is not being rendered properly

Comment: @LarsHoldaas, if i concat the index and the music name, how is it ? is it a good approach?

Comment: @DjBilljeOfficial Is your `musics` state array properly formed? This, to me, implies a data integrity issue, unrelated to react keys. Please share the `musics` array value. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the UI issue and share a link in your question?

Comment: @DjBilljeOfficial could you edit the post with your data?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ihws1f here is a rough example of your code. As far as I can see - if the data comes correctly, it must render. So the problem is somewhere when the data is getting to the variable. Also @Drew Reese you can update the answer with a working example, if you think it's necessary

Comment: @k.s i see, this is confusing, i am new to react so i dont know what i did in my code

Comment: @DjBilljeOfficial lets go by eliminating. Remove the code that goes after the buttons. The `<AudioPlayer  ` and the `<Header />`. In case they have some weird css that blocks it.

Comment: Please, I think this debugging discussion should occur in the main comments section.

Comment: @k.s OMG how stupid i am the size of <AudioPlayer> was not letting me click the button ffs, thank you guys and sorry guys. It was such a silly mistake lol. I removed <AudioPlayer> and it worked

Comment: @DjBilljeOfficial Aye, so it *was* another element on the screen blocking access to the list items. 

Comment: @DjBilljeOfficial don't forget to mark the answer as the correct one. As he did answer your question about the `key`