# React error with missing unique "key" prop when unique identifiers are already present

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sanity

The app is a portfolio using a React frontend and I am writing in Javascript, not Typescript. I am using Sanity as a headless CMS to store the data.

I am using useEffect to fetch the data. I am using a .map to loop over each section to render the following information for my site: skill.name, experience.year, work.name. Each of these sections is inside its own  and each has a unique key: skill.name, experience.year, work.name.

I know I have to give each child in a component a "unique 'key' prop" in React. What I am rendering has unique identifiers already: the skill.name, experience.year, work.name

The **error** being produced is as follows:
*Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `Skills`.*

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I am missing here?

```
<div className="app__skills-container">
    <motion.div className="app__skills-list">
      {/* fetch Skills from Sanity CMS and map over them*/}
      {skills?.map((skill) => (
        <motion.div whileInView={{ opacity: [0, 1] }} transition={{ duration: 0.5 }} `enter code here`className="app__skills-item app__flex" key={skill.name}>
          <div className="app__flex" style={{ backgroundColor: skill.bgColor }}>
            <img src={urlFor(skill.icon)} alt={skill.name} />
          </div>

<motion.div className="app__skills-exp">
      {/* {console.log("----- skills-exp:", experience.works)} */}
      {experiences.map((experience) => (
        <motion.div className="app__skills-exp-item" key={experience.year}>
          <div className="app__skills-exp-year">
            <p className="bold-text">{experience.year}</p>
          </div>
          <motion.div className="app__skills-exp-works">
            {/* 1st loops of year, then loop over the experiences contained within */}
            {experience.works.map((work) => (
              <>
                <motion.div
                  whileInView={{ opacity: [0, 1] }}
                  transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
                  className="app__skills-exp-work"
                  data-tip
                  data-for={work.name}
                  key={work.name}
                >
                  <h4 className="bold-text">{work.name}</h4>
                  <p className="p-text">{work.company}</p>
                </motion.div>
```

Comment: In your map over `experience.works` there's a fragment, which is the child element of the map and therefore what needs the key, no?

Comment: you miss '=' in this line `<motion.div className="app__skills-exp-item" key {experience.year}>`. It should be `<motion.div className="app__skills-exp-item" key={experience.year}>`

Comment: @Geoff Ball - I see what you're saying but, the code block above may not show the whole picture. I am using framer-motion so, the div that opens to contain the map over experience.works is a <motion.div> Then, I map over, the map then returns a fragment, then a another motion.div, AND a ReactToolTip. Because I want the map method to return 2 tags, I use a fragment. 

The key inside this map (work.name) is inside the the opening <motion.div> tag

Comment: @yohanes - not sure what you mean, key={experience.year} is included in the code block above in my original post.

Comment: did you copy-paste the code or type it manually?

Comment: @yohanes I copy/pasted sections of my code above for the original post

Comment: <motion.div className="app__skills-exp-item" key {experience.year}> is original code?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure that no keys repeat you can always use helper index in `map` like this:

```
<TableBody>
    {
        products ?
            (
                products.length > 0 ?
                    products.map((product, idx) => (
                        <TableRowProduct
                            key={idx}
                            item={product}
                        />
                    ))
                    :
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell align="center" colSpan={columns.length}>
                            <Alert severity="info">The list is empty/Alert>
                        </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
            )
            :
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell align="center" colSpan={columns.length}><CircularProgress/></TableCell>
            </TableRow>
    }
</TableBody>
```

Comment: Ok, this is interesting. I see what you're suggesting and I've applied it here. Each time I use .map I have added index as a paramter and then inside each opening div, I have made the unique identifier the item, ex: item={work.name} and then added the index for key, ex: key={index}. 

I am still seeing the same error: react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:117 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Skills`.

Comment: well, if had problem like this I'd start from rendering just outer part: `skills.map` - if it goes right, I'd add `experiences.map` and finally `experiences.works.map` - just to pinpoint the problem. It would help if you post some sample data so anyone could run the code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65212709/11356202), the key has to be on the outermost child of the map. That's not the case in `experience.works.map()`, so I'd be interested if the error would go away if you were to change `<>` to `<React.Fragment key={work.name}>`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Point well taken. I removed the fragment and replaced it with a React. fragment tag but the error persists. The console log shows that the work names are not the same, so I am really not sure where this message is coming from.

Comment: In that case, I would add an index to each map (second param) and test it as the key in each map, just in case one of those current keys is not unique.