# My console is giving me "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." despite I gave a unique key

Tags: reactjs, arrays, filter, map-function

My console keep giving me this error

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

despite that I gave a unique key to my map list. My code looks like this:

```
const [cardItem, setCardItem] = useState(data); 

const uniqueIds = [];

const uniqueCat = cardItem.filter((element) => {
    const isDuplicate = uniqueIds.includes(element.category);

    if (!isDuplicate) {
      uniqueIds.push(element.category);

      return true;
    }

    return false;
  });
return (
<>
<div className="art-container">
        {uniqueCat
          .filter((id) => id.id < 73)
          .map((item, i) => {
            return item.category === "Filmmaking" ||
              item.category === "Multimedia" ? (
              <div key={i}>
                <div className="art-projects-contants">
                  <h1>{item.category}</h1>
                  <Card cardItem={cardItem} cat={item.category} />
                </div>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <>
                <div key={i} className="art-img-projects-contants" >
                  <h1>{item.category}</h1>
                  <Img cardItem={cardItem} cat={item.category} />
                </div>
              </>
            );
          })}
 </>
  );
```

I tried to give it a key with the id by {item.id} also giving the second div a key but it still give me the same error. Could the problem be from the uniqueCat because it gave two arrays when I console log it as in the picture?

[image]

How can I fix the Unique key problem?

Note: I am using map function in other places in my project but its the only place I have this error.

Comment: Well the second case does not include key prop :)

Comment: @DanielLazar I added a key to the second div and it still give me the same error, any other ideas ?

Comment: The fragment (`<>`) needs a key, not the `div` inside of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop even tho it has unique key React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65212632/warning-each-child-in-a-list-should-have-a-unique-key-prop-even-tho-it-has-un)

Comment: @xehpuk yess finally that worked thanks a lot :)))

Answer (score 0):

Your first div has a key, while your second does not:

```
<div className="art-container">
        {uniqueCat
        .filter((id) => id.id < 73)
        .map((item, i) => {
            return item.category === "Filmmaking" ||
            item.category === "Multimedia" ? (
            <div key={i}>
                <div className="art-projects-contants">
                <h1>{item.category}</h1>
                <Card cardItem={cardItem} cat={item.category} />
                </div>
            </div>
            ) : (
            <>
                <div  key={i} className="art-img-projects-contants" > // <== add key here
                <h1>{item.category}</h1>
                <Img cardItem={cardItem} cat={item.category} />
                </div>
            </>
            );
        })}
</div>
```

Comment: I gave the second div a key but it still give the same error

Answer (score 0):

The `key` must be unique on every element in the component tree, your index (`i`) may have already been used on a different element, avoid using just the loop index as the key.

It's best to use an actual `id` from the filtered `uniqueCat` because this id will most likely be unique from any other `id`s.

#### Sample code

```js
<div className="art-container">
  {uniqueCat
    .filter((id) => id.id < 73)
    .map((item) => {
      return item.category === 'Filmmaking' ||
        item.category === 'Multimedia' ? (
        <div key={item.id}>...</div>
      ) : (
        <div key={item.id}>...</div>
      );
    })}
</div>;
```

If the `id`s isn't very unique then you can do some form concatenation with template strings using the loop index.

Like this

```js
<div className="art-container">
  {uniqueCat
    .filter((id) => id.id < 73)
    .map((item, i) => {
      return item.category === 'Filmmaking' ||
        item.category === 'Multimedia' ? (
        <div key={`{item.id}-${i}`}>...</div>
      ) : (
        <div key={`{item.id}-${i}`}>...</div>
      );
    })}
</div>;
```

Comment: unfortunately that didnt work too, still giving the same error :(

Comment: Is the code you shared in the question your `Arts` component? @saraasash